# Laravel : @include

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use @include. But i got this error : `Undefined variable: bookOther (View: /home/infinitr/pinus.infinitree.eco/modules/Tour/Views/frontend/guest_list.blade.php)`

How can i fix it?

The Controller :

```
public function guests_list($id){
            $booking = Booking::where('id', $id)->first();
            $bookOther = BookOther::where('booking_id', '=', $booking->id)->get();
            
            return view('Tour::frontend.guest_list', ['booking'=>$booking, 'bookOther'=>$bookOther, 'layout'=>'guest_list']);
            
        }
```

The Route :

```
Route::get('/guest_list/{id}', '\Modules\Tour\Controllers\TourController@guests_list')->name('guest_list');
```

The blade :

```
<div id="booking-customer-{{$booking->id}}" class="tab-pane fade"><br>
 @include('Tour::frontend.guest_list')
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the variable in the `@include`

```
@include('Tour::frontend.guest_list',[
    'bookOther' => $bookOther,
])
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to change:

```
return view('Tour::frontend.guest_list', ['booking'=>$booking, 'bookOther'=>$bookOther, 'layout'=>'guest_list']);
```

To this:

```
return view('Tour::frontend.guest_list', compact('booking','bookOther', 'layout');
```